# Registering Angular elements using TypeScript ES6 modules and RequireJS

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, typescript, ecmascript-6, amd

I'm looking to convert an existing AMD based Angular application to use the new TypeScript 1.5 ES6 module syntax. Currently we have all modules in separate files, with the main "*app*" module defined as...

```
define('app', ['angular'], (angular) => {  
    return angular.module('app', []);
});
```

... and all Angular elements registered using the `require()` method e.g.

```
require(['app'], (app: ng.IModule) => {
    app.config(config);
    function config() {
        // Some config
    }
});
```

However using the TypeScript ES6 module syntax, AMD modules are generated with the `define()` method e.g.

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    ...
});
```

We have previously been using ASP.NET Bundling & Minification (System.Web.Optimization) and outputting the bundle directly as a `<script>` tag. However when trying to include the AMD modules declared with the `define()` method we encounter the common [MISMATCHED ANONYMOUS DEFINE() error](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch).

None of the recommendations seem ideal or work for us, so how should this be done correctly given that TypeScript compiles modules into anonymous `define()` calls?

Answer (score 0):

I bundle Typescript ES6 modules using the NPM TsProject gulp adaptor. Check out the [TsProjectTodoMVC](https://github.com/ToddThomson/tsproject/tree/master/TsProjectTodoMVC) app that shows how to get a single js using Typescript ES6 module bundles, Angular 1.4.7 and AMD/Require.